# R Data Table Assign Subset of Rows and Columns with Zero

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to explode a data table into a time series by populating future time steps with values of zero. The starting data table has the following structure. Values for `V1` and `V2` can be thought of as values for the first time step.

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3), V1 = c(1,2,3), V2 = c(4,5,6))
   ID V1 V2
1:  1  1  4
2:  2  2  5
3:  3  3  6
```

What I want to get to is a data table like this

```
    ID year V1 V2
1:   1    1  1  4
2:   1    2  0  0
3:   1    3  0  0
4:   1    4  0  0
5:   1    5  0  0
6:   2    1  2  5
7:   2    2  0  0
8:   2    3  0  0
9:   2    4  0  0
10:  2    5  0  0
11:  3    1  3  6
12:  3    2  0  0
13:  3    3  0  0
14:  3    4  0  0
15:  3    5  0  0
```

I've exploded the original data table and appended the `year` column with the following

```
dt <- dt[, .(year=1:5), by=ID][dt, on=ID, allow.cartesian=T]
    ID year V1 V2
 1:  1    1  1  4
 2:  1    2  1  4
 3:  1    3  1  4
 4:  1    4  1  4
 5:  1    5  1  4
 6:  2    1  2  5
 7:  2    2  2  5
 8:  2    3  2  5
 9:  2    4  2  5
10:  2    5  2  5
11:  3    1  3  6
12:  3    2  3  6
13:  3    3  3  6
14:  3    4  3  6
15:  3    5  3  6
```

Any ideas on how to populate columns `V1` and `V2` with zeros for `year!=1` would be much appreciated. I also need to avoid spelling out the `V1` and `V2` column names as the actual data table I'm working with has 58 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an error with that last step, but if you have a more recent version of data.table that behaves differently hten by all means just :

```
dt[year != 1, V1 := 0]  # logical condition in the 'i' position
dt[year != 1, V2 := 0]  # data.table assign in the 'j' position
```

Ooops. Didn't read to the end. Will see if I can test a range of columns.

Ranges can be constructed on the LHS of `data.table.[` assignment operator (`:=`):

```
> dt2[year != 1, paste0("V", 1:2) := 0 ]
> dt2
    ID V1 V2 year
 1:  1  1  4    1
 2:  1  0  0    2
 3:  1  0  0    3
 4:  1  0  0    4
 5:  1  0  0    5
 6:  2  2  5    1
 7:  2  0  0    2
 8:  2  0  0    3
 9:  2  0  0    4
10:  2  0  0    5
11:  3  3  6    1
12:  3  0  0    2
13:  3  0  0    3
14:  3  0  0    4
15:  3  0  0    5
```

Comment: I was a little slow :). `by = ID` is not needed.  You could also use ` grep("^V", names(dt), value = TRUE)` as  a different way to get the columns instead of doing `paste0()`. +1.

Comment: Right. The by was in there because I made a thinko and had `by=year` at first. :-)

Comment: That's interesting. I wasn't clear in that my column names have no pattern to them. I need to retain the column names. However, this sparked an idea to change the column names temporarily, use your approach, then rename back.
For completeness, is there a way to do this using `.SD`? I tried using `.SD` with `.SDcols=!c("ID","year")` but this throws an error.

Comment: The final version of IRTFM's answer that I settled on is the following: `dt[year != 1, (names(dt)[!grepl("ID|year",names(dt))]) := 0]`. Thanks for your help. Simple in hindsight, as usual.

Comment: If you had first sorted you columns by name you would have been able to use the alpha range operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::complete` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(year = 1) %>%
  complete(ID, year = 1:5, fill = list(V1 = 0, V2 = 0))

#      ID  year    V1    V2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     4
# 2     1     2     0     0
# 3     1     3     0     0
# 4     1     4     0     0
# 5     1     5     0     0
# 6     2     1     2     5
# 7     2     2     0     0
# 8     2     3     0     0
# 9     2     4     0     0
#10     2     5     0     0
#11     3     1     3     6
#12     3     2     0     0
#13     3     3     0     0
#14     3     4     0     0
#15     3     5     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah. However, I need to avoid spelling out the column names. There are 58 column names in the actual data table I'm working with, and there is no pattern to the names.

Comment: In that case you can use `replace` - `dt %>% mutate(year = 1) %>% complete(ID, year = 1:5) %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)`